# Laravel artisan not reading all environment vars

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel 5.2 app setup on an AWS Opsworks server. The web browser interface works perfectly. But when I try to run an Artisan command at the command line (php artisan xxxxxxx) I keep getting a mysql connection error [2002]. So I narrowed it down to the environment variables. We have 40 variables defined in the .env file. I started by adding some simple echo statements to my artisan script to echo out the database connection vars. It would only echo the database name. The host, user and pass were coming up blank. I thought maybe laravel was just being clever and not echoing those for security. So I decided to echo ALL environment variables in the artisan script. Only 2 of them would echo. The rest are blank. Any reason why laravel's artisan can't read most of the environment vars in .env?

Comment: check the syntax i would tell you to post the .env but no programmer would want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came down to how AWS implements the database connection vars. When AWS deploys it puts that information in the apache configuration. However, due to the nature of CLI, there is no Apache figured into the picture. So, we had to create a chef recipe that runs last and grabs the freshly written env vars from the apache config and creates the .env file. It's rather redundant, but seems to be working ok now.